# What is the KeyField name used for on aspxgridview

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I am using the DevExpress aspxgridview in work.

The documentation says you need to specify a key field name but I cant find a reason beyond, because we said so. Does anyone know what this is for? Do I only need one, or one for each field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `KeyFieldName` is like a `primary key` for the `Grid row`, to `uniquely identify a row` in the grid. Lets say, you want to delete or edit a row, and click the Delete Command Button on the browser. How does the grid know which record you meant to delete? Also, if you need to update your database based on grid actions, you would expect the primary key of the grid row, which is the `KeyFieldName`.

`KeyFieldName` can be one or more datafields in your grid datasource (if multiple datafields, separate by a semi-colan). KeyFieldName is for each grid row, not each column.

Comment: That makes sense, so the best candidate to set then is the primary key.